# Array of strings output, missing characters, ncurses

Tags: c, arrays, ncurses

In a separate .txt file, I have: **de4 dw9 ds8 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2**

The function below cuts the string up into an array.
The output of the array is this:

**de4 / w9 / s8 / g8,7 / m3,4 / p2,2 / (null)**

As you can see, the "w9" and "s8" are missing the 'd'. I cannot seem to figure out why. Here is my function:

```
void parseFile(char ** argv)
{
FILE * textFile;
char * string;
char ** lineToken;
int i;

textFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
lineToken = malloc(sizeof(char *) + 1);
string = malloc(sizeof(char *) + MAX_CHAR);

while(fgets(string, MAX_CHAR, textFile) != NULL)
{
    lineToken[0] = strtok(string, " "); /* Put first element in lineToken[0] */

    for(i = 1; string != NULL; i++)
    {
        lineToken = realloc(lineToken, (sizeof(char *) * (i + 1))); /* Realloc since total number of elements is unknown */

        if(lineToken == NULL) /* Check to see if reallocing caused an error */
        {
            move(0,0);
            printw("Error reallocing. Press any key to close program.");
            refresh();
            getch();
            exit(0);
            endwin();
        }

        lineToken[i] = strtok(NULL, " "); /* Put new strtok'd string into lineToken[i] */
        system("clear");
        move(0,0);
        printw("%s", lineToken[i]);
        refresh();
        getch();

    }        
}

for(i = 0; lineToken[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    system("clear");
    move(0,0);
    printw("%s", lineToken[i]);
    refresh();
    getch();
}

fclose(textFile);
free(string);
free(lineToken);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There are two pretty obvious problems:

The first is the condition for the inner loop when reading from the file, `string != NULL`. unless the allocation of `string` failed initially this condition will always be true. You need to check the return of `strtok` instead: `lineToken[i - 1] != NULL`.

The second problem is that you only have a single "array" for all lines you read. So if you have more than a single line in the file you overwrite all tokens you read from the first line.

---

A third problem: If the reallocation fails, you `exit` the program. However, you have code *after* that `exit` call, and the `exit` function does not return so the call to `endwin` will not happen in that case.

Comment: And a fourth problem, *when* `lineToken[i] = strtok(NULL, " ")` returns NULL (and it will eventually), the followup `printw("%s", lineToken[i])` invokes UB.